# Updating SQL database entries

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, visual-studio

I'm currently attempting to introduce an update option for my form project. I can successfully save entries to the database, but I want to be able to update these entries if the user gets information in the future that needs to be updated within the database...

Currently my error is, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near'"lossID=8, 25 Oct, 00:00, 25 Oct, 23:59,","" at line 1.

I thought this would be from perhaps the set syntax but I get the same error if I remove it or change anything there. I'm not sure if its because I am using parameters for my insert function, and perhaps just missing something?

My code for this is,

```
if (start_time.Text == end_time.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please input a different ending time for the loss event");

        }
        else
        {
            string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234; ";
            string query = "update lossdatabase.losstable set (lossID= '" + this.textBox1.Text + "', @Start, @Start_Time, @End, @End_Time, @Equipment, @Event, @Responsibility, @Cause, @Reason, Capacity_Loss='" + capacity + "', Planned= '" + Planned + "', Scheduled='" + Scheduled + "', Prepared='" + Prepared + "', @Primary_Rate, @Primary_Volume, @Primary_Percentage, @Secondary_Rate, @Secondary_Volume, @Secondary_Percentage, @Comment) where lossID= '" + this.textBox1.Text + "' ;";
            //Defines the connection string to allow data to be deposited into the database, along with defining the variables and columns for the data to be added to


            MySqlConnection conLossDB = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdLossDB = new MySqlCommand(query, conLossDB);


            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", start_date.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_Time", start_time.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", end_date.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End_Time", end_time.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Equipment", comboBox1.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Event", comboBox2.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Responsibility", comboBox3.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cause", richTextBox1.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", richTextBox2.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Primary_Rate", Rate_box.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Primary_Volume", Volume_box.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Primary_Percentage", Percentage_box.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Secondary_Rate", Rate_2.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Secondary_Volume", Volume_2.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Secondary_Percentage", Percentage_2.Text);
            cmdLossDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", richTextBox3.Text);

            //Defines which boxes to read in order to input the text from the defined boxes into the corresponding columns


            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conLossDB.Open();
                myReader = cmdLossDB.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("The loss entry has successfully been updated");
                //Opens the database and carries out the defined command outlined in the code above
                this.Close();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Google "Syntax for UPDATE Command"

Comment: why you wrote lossID= '" + this.textBox1.Text + "', Start
do you need start in lossID column?

Comment: Why arent you passing that ID as a parameter like the others? Dont store dates/times as string or pass them as string.